Slopes of Translations of Convex Functions
Suppose I have a strictly increasing, continuous, convex (non-linear) function $w:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$. Let $\{\alpha_i\}_1^n$ be weights that sum to 1.
Fix some $x^*\in \mathbb{R}.$ Also fix any alphas. Suppose I know that there exist, for these alphas, $\{x_i\}_1^n$ such that:
(1) $w(x^*)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iw(x_i),$ and
(2) $w(x^*+a)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iw(x_i+a)$
for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. So, the equality is preserved through any translation.
I want to claim that this holds if and only if $x_i=x^*$ for each $i$. I can only gain intuition through examples at this point. I'm struggling to prove it for all convex functions.
Also I'm interested in an analogous claim for concave functions. Also functions with concave, convex, and even linear segments.
EDIT: I now realize this is not true, but I want to know how I can add additional restrictions onto 1 and 2 to ensure that $x_i=x^*$ for all i. Thanks!

The first condition is superfluous, just set $a=0$ in the second. Also, any affine function satisfies (2) automatically.

Try $n=2,$ $x_1=0,$ $x_2=1,$ $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\frac12$ and let $w$ be the natural exponential function. Then $x^*=\ln\frac{1+e}2$ and for all $a\in\mathbb R$
$$w(x^*+a)=\exp(x^*)\exp(a)=\frac{\exp(a)+\exp(a+1)}2=\alpha_1w(x_1+a)+\alpha_2w(x_2+a).$$

Thank you so much! Do you know what kind of restrictions I would need in order to claim that $x_i=x^*$ for all $i$? That's my goal and I am struggling to create restrictions. I have (1) and (2), which are not enough clearly. Thanks again!

I would at least require $\alpha_i>0,$ and then some kind of restriction on $x^*,$ for example requiring that it be the weighted sum of the $x_i.$
